# Domain Service Return Custom Class Result

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

I want return two types to the calling method, i know that we cannot use out or ref in WCF RIA.

i have created a custom class to get necessary info like this :

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Web_GetPrivilegesResult  {
        [Include]
        [DataMember]
        public List<tblPrivilege> ResultList { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid? ParentGroupID { get; set; }
    }

    [Invoke]
    public Web_GetPrivilegesResult Web_GetPrivileges(Guid id, bool isSuperAdmin, bool isEnable, bool returnAccessListIfDisbaled) {
        ...
    }
```

On the client side (silverlight application) when the function is called, it returns only `ParentGroupID` - `ResultList` isn't retruned. how can i correct this ?

**UPDATE**

Last changed Codes :

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Web_GetPrivilegesResult  {
        //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Composition]
        //[Include]
        [DataMember]
        public List<tblPrivilege> Result { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid? ParentGroupID { get; set; }
    }

    //[Query]

    [Invoke]
    public Web_GetPrivilegesResult Web_GetPrivileges(Guid id, bool isSuperAdmin, bool isEnable, bool returnAccessListIfDisbaled) {
        tblUsersAndGroup usersAndGroup = new tblUsersAndGroup() { ID = id, IsSuperAdmin = isSuperAdmin, IsEnable = isEnable };

        Guid? parentGroupID;
        List<tblPrivilege> result = GetPrivileges(usersAndGroup, out parentGroupID, returnAccessListIfDisbaled, this.DataContext);

        //System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions options = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
        //options.LoadWith<Web_GetPrivilegesResult>(q => q.Result);
        //this.DataContext.LoadOptions = options;

        //List<Web_GetPrivilegesResult> res = new List<Web_GetPrivilegesResult>();
        //res.Add(new Web_GetPrivilegesResult() { ParentGroupID = parentGroupID, Result = result });


        return new Web_GetPrivilegesResult() { ParentGroupID = parentGroupID, Result = result };

    }
```

thanks

Comment: is not returned as in it is empty?

Comment: no ResultList property is not generated in silverlight and i cannot access to it

Answer (score 1):

Because of using `[Include]` attribute, In the query method, you must ensure that the associated entities are actually loaded by using the **Include** method on the query.

You will need to explicitly request (using LINQ to Entities) that the data for the `ResultList` propertiy on each Web_GetPrivilegesResult entity are retrieved from the database, using the `Include` method in the query, like so:

```
public IQueryable<Web_GetPrivilegesResult> GetPrivilegesResult()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Web_GetPrivilegesResult.Include("ResultList");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Just add `.Include("ResultList")` at the end of the `return` in your `Web_GetPrivileges(Guid id, bool isSuperAdmin, bool isEnable, bool returnAccessListIfDisbaled)` method !

**UPDATE2:**

You can see [this](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/05/21/include-for-linq-to-sql-and-maybe-other-providers) and [this](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/10/27/EntityFramework_Include_Equivalent_in_LINQ_to_SQL.aspx) for Linq2SQL equivalent of `Include()`

Comment: i am using LinqToSqlDomainService and i have static function that work with entity and and get result List of tblPrivilege, how can i use this way you say? thanks

Comment: where is Include method, i cannot found it, as you can see Include method is not member of Web_GetPrivilegesResult class, and also Web_GetPrivilegesResult is not datacontext entity...

Comment: i am remove [Include] and clean and rebuild solution but i cannot access to it, i update my question, please see it